# Google Earth Engine: Saving time-series pixel value data of a point feature to a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-earth-engine

Good day! I've been using Earth Engine for quite a few years now, but normally in Jupyter notebooks. As my current project is exploring Earth Engine using JavaScript - and I admit that I am not that well-versed in JS - then I will try to ask for help in this matter.

I am currently trying to save a year's worth of Sentinel-1 time-series VV and VH values of a point feature as an Array in JavaScript, in order to use in later coding (i.e. as temporal signatures for dynamic time warping (DTW)). Unfortunately, my search for possible means to do so largely ended up to be frustrating.

I tried some potential solutions such as this:

[Extract pixel values by points and convert to a table in Google Earth Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742742/extract-pixel-values-by-points-and-convert-to-a-table-in-google-earth-engine)

Yet still I couldn't figure out how to extract the VV and VH values from the resulting FeatureCollection.

I am imagining the 2-D Array to look like this, at minimum:

| image_id | VV |
| --- | --- |
| (S1 file # 1 with date) | VV value |
| (S1 file # 2 with date | VV value |
| ... | ... |

Any help on this possibly uncomplicated issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks!